# How to set a breakpoint on inline JavaScript in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Here is some example code:

```
<a href="javascript:void('Add media')" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(19,this);return false;">
```

Is there a way to set a breakpoint so when I click to fire off callFunction the debugger kicks in? I tried editing the inline function and prepend with `debugger;` but the debugger behaves weirdly and doesn't step into where I thought it would.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a `debugger` inline:

```
<a href="javascript:void('Add media')" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(19,this); debugger; return false;">
```

Comment: My question includes the fact that I tried that exact thing and it doesn't work as expected.